# How to do Multi-hot Encoding but with actual values instead of ones

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, multi-hot-encoding

I am able to perform a Multi-hot encoding of ratings to movies by:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer


def multihot_encode(actual_values, ordered_possible_values) -> np.array:
    """ Converts a categorical feature with multiple values to a multi-label binary encoding """
    mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=ordered_possible_values)
    binary_format = mlb.fit_transform(actual_values)
    return binary_format

user_matrix = multihot_encode(lists_of_movieIds, all_movieIds)
```

where `arr_of_movieIds` is a batch_size sized list of variable length lists of movie IDs (strings) and `all_movieIds` are all the possible movie ID strings.

However, instead of just 1 on the resulting matrix I want to have the actual rating that a user gave to the movie. Just like `list_of_movieIds` I also have access to a "parallel" to that `list_of_ratings`.

How do I go about doing that efficiently? Is there another MultiLabelBinarizer which takes those as args? Can I do some fancy linear algebra to get there?

I tried to do it like:

```
user_matrix[user_matrix == 1] = np.concatenate(list_of_ratings)
```

but the ratings are misplaced because `list_of_ratings` is not ordered the same way as `all_movieIds`...

Answer (score 1):

Without using `MultiLabelBinarizer`

```
import numpy as np
classes=['comedy', 'xyz','thriller', 'sci-fi']
id_dict = {c:i for i,c in enumerate(classes)}
lists_of_movieIds = [{'sci-fi', 'thriller'}, {'comedy'}]
list_of_ratings = [[4,3],[5]]

data = np.zeros((len(lists_of_movieIds), len(classes)))
for i, (m_ids,rs) in enumerate(zip(lists_of_movieIds, list_of_ratings)):
  for m_id,r in zip(m_ids,rs):
    data[i, id_dict[m_id]] = r

print (data)
```

Output:

```
[[0. 0. 3. 4.]
 [5. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the point was to avoid python for-loops and use vectorized operations because I believe that would slow things down more.

Comment: I ended up sorting my dataset on movieId when creating it and using the masking approach I mentioned in the post as a temporary (probably permanent if I don't find anything better) and risky solution.